# Subsetting if contains multiple variables in a certain order

Tags: r, dplyr

In my dataframe, I have two columns of interest: `id` and `name` - my goal is to only keep records of `id` where `id` has more than one value in `name`  ***and***  where the final value in `name` is 'B' .

The sample data would look like this:

```
> test
   id name
1   1    A
2   2    A
3   3    A
4   4    A
5   5    A
6   6    A
7   7    A
8   2    B
9   1    B
10  2    A
```

and the output would look like this:

```
> output
   id name
1   1    A
9   1    B
```

How would one filter to get these rows in R ?   I know that you can filter by the those with multiple variables using the `%in%` operator but am not sure how to add in the condition that 'B' must be the last record.  I am not opposed to using a package like `dplyr` but a solution in base R would be ideal.  Any suggestions?

Here is the sample data:

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1, 2), name = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A")), .Names = c("id", 
"name"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr`,

```
test %>% 
 group_by(id) %>% 
 filter(n_distinct(name) > 1 & last(name) == 'B')

#Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
#Groups: id [1]

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     id  name
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1     1     A
#2     1     B
```

Answer (score 0):

In `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, .SD[length(unique(name)) >= 2 & name[.N] == "B"],by = .(id)]
#   id name
#1:  1    A
#2:  1    B
```